# C# RestSharp Getting an list of items returns null

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have the following class for a rental Property: Also tried lowercase property.

```
public class Property
{
    public string address1 { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following code to access the list of properties from the server. I do know the property JSON is proper as I can get a single one form the server.

```
var request = api.Request ("/api/properties");
request.RootElement = "property";
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
var des = new JsonDeserializer();

//IRestResponse<List<property>> response = client.Execute<List<property>>(request);
//List<property> props = response.Data;
//gives the same error in ErrorMessage

IRestResponse<RootObject> response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);
RootObject props = response.Data;
var dd = des.Deserialize<RootObject> (response);
```

And the following is the RootObject:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Property> property { get; set; }
}
```

As shown above I also used List (Commented out)

All give me the same thing: System.InvalidCastException : Cannot cast from source type to Destination type.

I am totally frustrated right now attempting to figure this out and totally lost.

Comment: Can you show some JSON results?  You said: _"I do know the property JSON is proper as I can get a single one form the server."_  Are you referring to a single `RootObject` or a single `Property|property`.

Comment: So what does he JSON look like when you receive many `property` items at the same time?  (Just show two)

Comment: Single using <Property>
 {"name":"Demo Property","address1":"2191 South Kihei Rd"}

Retrieving multiple properties: neither <List<Property>> nor <RootObject>  work. These are from printing out the content 
[{"name":"Luxury Maui Vista","address1":"2191 South Kihei St."},{"name":"Demo Property","address1":"2191 South Kihei Rd"}]

Comment: What is received from the content field is the same whether <List<Property>> or <RootObject> the types are:  response.GetType = RestSharp.RestResponse`1[SharedLibrary.DL.RootObject] and type = RestSharp.RestResponse`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SharedLibrary.DL.Property]] when property